# Facebook PHP SDK throwing Unauthorized source IP address error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I recently discovered that one of our production servers is giving a fatal error when we try to issue an FQL query via the Graph API.  The exact same code on other servers works perfectly.  The servers are behind a load balancer with a single IP address.

The error is:

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#5) Unauthorized source IP address
  thrown in /usr/local/home/faniq/php-lib/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1039
```

I have tried adding the IP address to my FB app's server whitelist (which was blank). When I try to save the whitelist, it gives me this error: 
  Your IP should be included in the Server Whitelist.

I even tried a range of IP addresses, still refuses to save.  The other production servers and our development environments all work fine, so I am at a loss.  Any ideas why Facebook would not accept requests from this one particular server?

Comment: We stumbled upon the same kind of issue. Have you had any news? Related : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/184086621725161

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to enter a IP address in the Advanced Settings unless you want to restrict API calls from specific servers. Since your server(s) are behind a load balancer, you should enter the public IP for each server behind the load balancer, rather than the load balancer IP address.

The servers will be calling the API directly from each server, rather than going via the load balancer. The load balancer is only used for incoming requests to your server, not outgoing like API calls.